# How to link to a PDF file in Qt Assistant?

Tags: qt, pdf

I use Qt Assistant as a help viewer and I have an internal link to a PDF file that is  embedded into the compiled archive format. When I click on that link, nothing happens. How can I link to a PDF file that is embedded, click on the link and have an external application opened? I use Qt Assistant 4.7.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of bundling a program like [Okular](http://okular.kde.org/) into your application release and launching it as an external process there isn't a native way of arriving at your solution. More options are discussed [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/13682-How-to-display-PDF-in-Qt) as well, to sum it up it's either externally or converting the PDF to a QPixmap.

Comment: I want add to, that Qt does not have PDF reading capabilities. Using pure Qt program to do the bundling could work, but I think Okular will work best for everything. Most often you want to leave that kind of opening a file to problem of system and just instruct people to install the reader (or for Windows launch autoinstaller with your installer).

Comment: +1 for the auto-installer. Always annoyed when I'm installing a system only to find out that I have to go download something else. ;)

Comment: OK thanks for the links, but this is beyond my ability (I use the standalone Qt Assistant) and just generate docs for that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this can work. To display a pdf file you need Acrobat or a similar (external) program, and this program needs a file to read. Why don't you store the pdf files outside the help file?

Comment: See the documentation just above http://ldc.usb.ve/docs/qt/assistant-manual.html#full-text-searching "Some pages contain links to PDF documents. In order to display these links, you must specify a PDF viewer. ..." Therefore I assumed it is still possible to do that, but the mentioned preference pane is not there anymore.

Comment: This documentation does not speak about embedded pdf documents but about links to (external) pdf files.